# React useCallback setting dependency on a function called inside the callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm working on a web app using react and saw this implemented there. It goes something like this:

```
const onAddNewAccount = useCallback(async () => {
   await refetch();
   setOtherState((prev) => {...});
},
[refetch]);
```

I don't understand why do this, is this actually something correct? Because from what I understand the callback will be called on one of the dependencies changing.

From what I've seen calling `refetch` won't actually trigger `useCallback` probably because it is just called right? not changed.

So basically I need help understanding why they did this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the callback will be called on one of the dependencies changing.

No, it won't be called, it will just be recreated. The purpose of `useCallback` is to memoize the function and reuse it if nothing has changed. In other words, it's trying to make it so `onAddNewAccount` from render 1 === `onAddNewAccount` from render 2.

If `refetch` changes, then the memoization will break and a new function is created. That way the new `onAddNewAccount` can call the new refetch if needed. If `refetch` never changes, then that's great: the memoization can last forever then.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. So `refetch` is in the deps in case this component is called from another parent component with a different refetch implementation, is that it?

Comment: that way `onAddNewAccount` will be recreated with the different refetch method

Comment: `in case this component is called from another parent component with a different refetch implementation` It's there in case refetch changes from one render to the next. For example, if the parent component rerenders and creates a new refetch function. `that way onAddNewAccount will be recreated with the different refetch method ` Correct